# Catching the stack trace from one form that passing from another

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

am in a big problem.. i try searching for a half of day, here is my problem.
I am creating an app using c# and .net v4.0 (client profile version) that's generate a PDFs report when an exception trow, what i want to do is i want to get the stack trace to my report when an error occur, i know how to get the stack trace when an error occur, but i need to know how can i pass it to the another windows form that display the stack trace and give user a chance to review it before sending how can i pass my stack trace to another form please help
 thnax in advance !

here is the code i used to get the exception's stack trace

```
try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\niyo\Documents\TESTs\hfkdjhfkhd.text");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string trace = ex.StackTrace;
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
    frmProto frm = new frmProto();
    frm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public static Exception formException;
try
{
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\niyo\Documents\TESTs\hfkdjhfkhd.text");
}
 catch (Exception ex)
{
formException = ex;
MessageBox.Show("Test");
frmProto frm = new frmProto();
frm.Show();
this.Hide();
}
```

On your new form use this:

Exception form1_Exception = Form1.formException;

Parse a whole Exception object because that contains the error message. Sometimes the error message is more helpfull than the stacktrace because the Error Message is very clear.

Also many times it is the InnerException of the Exception object that is more helpfull.

Good Luck!

Complete sample i did:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static Exception formException;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int.Parse("This will raise and excpetion because i can't convert this to an int... ");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                formException = ex;
                Form2 frm = new Form2();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And on your second form:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show(Form1.formException.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Jackson, thank you for the answer... , but the thing is i need to use this inside of the button click event .. :(

Comment: Hi Nilan, Check out the new sample i posted in my answer.

Comment: There is no need to statically link the forms like this. That would mean you could only handle exceptions thrown in form1

Comment: @JamesBarrass I think Nilan has a specific form that generates an PDF report for errors. So in fact he could change the constructor of his PDF report form to accept a Exception object as param. That means he could handle exceptions from all forms.

Comment: Thank you So much, yes Jackson i am going to generate a pdf report automatically when an exception thrown, Jackson..... it's a good example..i'm working on automated error reporting system will update you all with my progress ... thank you all KIT. :)

Comment: I'm glad i could help. Please let us know how it goes and if you need more help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

on Form1:

```
try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\niyo\Documents\TESTs\hfkdjhfkhd.text");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string trace = ex.StackTrace;
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
    frmProto frm = new frmProto();
       frm.trace=trace;
    frm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

on Form2 :

```
   public static string trace;
     MessageBox.Show(trace);
```

Comment: in my case trace pass the null value to the second form,  am using this in a button click event...!

Comment: I edited see above...trace was null until the exception..When you click on button in Form2 the exception must have occured else Form2 would'nt have been created